# $f(k) = \int_{k-1}^{k} f(k) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

According to my literature, for $f(k) = k^{-a}$, it is true that
$f(k) = \int_{k-1}^{k} f(k) dx$. I have tried with different k's and a's and it has always checked out but I don't know how to "see" it for myself.

I have gone through this part before and I remember getting it back then, but now it seems totally confusing to me.

Comment: Hint: $f(k)$ does not depend on $x$. Hence the claim follows.

Comment: Oh my, yup, makes sense. It was driving me mad. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are integrating over $x$, $f(k)$ can just be treated as a constant, so that
$$\int_{k-1}^k f(k) dx = f(k)\int_{k-1}^k 1 dx = f(k)(k-(k-1)) = f(k).$$